# Hyperledger consensus

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, consensus

Correct me if I am wrong, or confirm, is consensus synchronizing history between peers?

Each peer stores all transactions history?

Each peer is running on separated machines or all peers are running on same machine(in docker for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply the consensus or (total-order broadcast, atomic broadcast) done between peers are on same channel.

Ordering service provides a shared communication channel to clients and peers, offering a broadcast service for messages containing transactions. Clients connect to the channel and may broadcast messages on the channel which are then delivered to all peers.

The channel supports atomic delivery of all messages, that is, message communication with total-order delivery and (implementation specific) reliability. In other words, the channel outputs the same messages to all connected peers and outputs them to all peers in the same logical order. This atomic communication guarantee is also called total-order broadcast, atomic broadcast, or consensus in the context of distributed systems. The communicated messages are the candidate transactions for inclusion in the blockchain state.

Answer (score 0):

Consensus is the process of multiple peers determining if their records of transactions match.  With Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6, all of the blocks on the ledger will match across peers if the peers are in consensus.  In this version, each validating peer does store all transactions.

Hyperledger Fabric version 1.0 which is under development should make it possible for a subset of participants in a blockchain network to process certain transactions.  Information on the [future consensus architecture](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/proposals/r1/Next-Consensus-Architecture-Proposal.md) has more details.

The peers usually run in multiple Docker containers that are owned by one entity when using Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.  With upcoming Hyperledger Fabric version 1.0 it should be possible for one entity to start a blockchain network and then invite other parties (such as other companies) to join.  In this case, peers would be distributed across multiple entities.